# Django: Values list for a many to many relation

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I'd like to know why I cannot get the item names in the same order as they are presented in the QuerySet when using `values_list`.

```
print(self.prd_obj.basket.values_list())
<QuerySet [(2, 27, Decimal('20.00')), (1, 23, Decimal('12.50')), (3, 28, Decimal('15.00'))]>
```

(above is understood as id 2 item on a ManyToMany list, this item in turn refers to id 27 on a global items list. On the global item list, id 27 is Honda that costs 20, id 28 is Mazda that costs 15 and id 23 is Ford that costs 12.50)

The same order re-appear when I ask for price, as below.

```
print(self.prd_obj.basket.values_list('price'))
<QuerySet [(Decimal('20.00'),), (Decimal('12.50'),), (Decimal('15.00'),)]>
```

However, when asking for brand (through the items field) the order is not the same.
Later when re-assembly the values, Honda now costs 15, Mazda 12.50, and Ford 20.00

```
print(self.prd_obj.basket.values_list('items__brand'))
<QuerySet [('Ford',), ('Mazda',), ('Honda',)]>
```

This is the Model for the basket, I refer to this as a ManyToMany field as I needed a model to connect Item with a price.

```
class ShoppingBasketItem(models.Model):
    items = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, blank=True, null=True)
```

Why is it happening and is there a better way to refer to item and its price within a "shopping basket"?

Comment: use `values()` instead of `values_list()` ?

Comment: @Arakkal_Abu , tried, no difference